# How to generate ~/.config/monitors.xml file from a script?

Tags: multiple-monitors, lightdm, display-manager

I'm writing a script that set ups multi-head configurations, it generates an `xorg.conf` file and runs an `xrandr` command to setup the displays.

This works fine until the computer reboots and logs back in, at some point the `~/.config/monitors.xml` file overwrites my `xorg.conf` changes.  I don't particularly want to write my own `monitors.xml` generator so I tried just deleting it before making my `xorg.conf`/`xrandr` changes, but, the `monitors.xml` file appears to be auto-generated on reboot, and my settings get overridden anyway.

If I launch 'Display Settings' and click 'Apply' and save the configuration that generates a `monitors.xml` file which is set up correctly, but it'd be a lot better if I could do that from a script. Is it possible?

Comment: The easy solution is to run a set of `xrandr` commands *a few seconds after* log in, setting up your configuration correctly.

Comment: That solution would probably work for the current devices but we're planning on doing some multi video card set ups as well where we won't be using xrandr and we'll need the monitors.xml file working then.  It's not too bad to generate the monitors.xml file but it seems like there would be a way to do it from the terminal built in.